# Two tables get values with common value or no value in other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

We have two tables.

Table 1 - Users: Contains the users

Table 2 - Restrictions: User that can only access certain room. If a user is not in this table they can access all the rooms.

[image]

Now I need a query where I pass the room and it returns the users that have access. For example, I pass RoomId = 70 and my expected result is 1, 3.
1 because it actually has access to only room 70 and 3 because since it's not in the restriction table it has access to all rooms.

The problem is with an inner join I lose number 3, and with left join I keep number 2. So I cannot figure out **how to relate the tables**. Is there any way to do it directly with joins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `UNION`

```
SELECT usr.UserID  FROM Users usr 
JOIN Restrictions res ON usr.UserID = res.UserID
WHERE res.RoomID = @myParameter --we take the users permitted for given room

UNION

SELECT UserID
FROM Users
WHERE UserID NOT IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT UserID
        FROM Restriction
        ) --plus the users that have permission in all rooms
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, this should work. You don't really need a `join` to solve the issue.

```
select 
     userid
from
     users u
where
     userid is not in (
        select 
            userid 
        from 
            restrictions 
        where 
            userid = u.userid 
            and roomid = @roomId
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advise you not to use `not in` with a subquery.  It is just a dangerous habit.  If the subquery returns *any* `NULL` values, then the outer query returns *no rows*.

So, I would recommend:

```
select userid
from users u
where exists (select 1
              from restrictions r
              where r.userid = u.userid and
                    r.roomid = 70
             ) or
      not exists (select 1
                  from restrictions r
                  where r.userid = u.userid
                 );
```

I would also strongly advise you to change your data model.  If someone has access to one room and that row is deleted from `restrictions`, then they will have access to all rooms.  That seems dangerous.  You should explicitly list *all* rooms useres have access to.